# Appending children to Core Data objects

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm currently trying to parse JSON into Core Data objects. I parse the JSON into Categories and then Subcategories.

When I parse the subcategories I would like to insert them into the associated Category object. I can see that Xcode generates methods for this, but I can't figure out how to use them.

```
- (void)addSubCategoryObject:(SubCategory *)value {
```

I would like to add them one at the time, not all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
[aCategoryObject addSubCategoryObject:aSubCategoryObject];
```

Both objects need to exist before you make the call.

Comment: It seems impossible to call that method. However it is not necessary to do so. If the relationship has a inverse it's enough to append a 'parentCategory' to all subCategories.

Comment: Yes, but you should be able to add an object to either side of an inverse relationship. If you can't something is wrong somewhere. If the `addSubCategoryObject:` method shows up in the class header but you still can't call it then most likely you are assigning your `Category` instances to a generic NSManagedObject instead of the `Category` class.